# How do I detect if a system supports forking of processes in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fork

How can I figure out if an [operating system supports forking](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fork) like `os.fork()` without invoking the command itself?

I.e. does

```
import os
hasattr(os, 'fork')
```

return `False` under Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that returns `False`. That's a good way to do it.

Comment: You could also use `try/except` around `from os import fork`.